# ios - All image views with Haneke are flickering on reload data

Tags: ios, swift, caching, uicollectionview, haneke

I am using Haneke to handle images (cache, async download, etc...). So every time I call a reload data on my collection, all images become flickering. Is this a Haneke problem? Am I doing something wrong?

This is the piece of code on my cellForItem method:

```
if let url = object._property._url {
       self.imageView?.hnk_setImageFromURL(url, placeholder: UIImage(named: "blank"))
} else {
       self.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "blank")
}
```